# Undefine a Macro With Bjam Command Line

Tags: c++, bjam, b2

bjam allows users to define a C/C++ macro in the command line.

How about undefining a macro?

What I would like to achieve is to undefine NDEBUG macro in my release build.

Thanks in advance.